# Warning when comparing integers of different signs

Tags: c++

I've two very similar functions in 2 programs as follows.

```
/*
 * Function: isalphaString
 * Usage: isalphaString(str);
 * ----------------------------
 * Judge if all characters in the string is alpha.
 */
bool isalphaString(string str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
        if (! isalpha(str[i]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

the second function:

```
bool containsNonAlpha(string boardText) {
    for (int i = 0; i < boardText.size(); i++) {
        if (!isalpha(boardText[i])) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

but get two different compiling results. The first one I have no compiling warnings, but the second one I received a warning: "comparison of integers of different signs" . Not sure why this happens.

Comment: warning details: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'int' and 'size_type' (aka 'unsigned long') [-Wsign-compare]

Comment: My compiler (g++-4.8) give me a warning with the first code snippet too, as it should.  Does that example come from a place where warnings are suppressed, for example a header in an include path specified with `-isystem `instead of `-I`?

Comment: I use qt creator and I think maybe you mean it's the .pro file configuration difference?

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare an `int` with `std::string::size_type`, you need to change this line:

```
for (int i = 0; i < boardText.size(); i++)
```

to:

```
for (string::size_type i = 0; i < boardText.size(); i++)
```

altought you can use a range-loop in *C++11* that is much simpler:

```
for(char &c : boardText) {
    check_if_alpha(c);
}
```

Comment: You can compare an `int` with `std::string::size_type`.  There's just a gotcha when you do, hence the compiler warning.

Comment: Yes but it's a bad practice, things start getting weird if the integer has negative values.